# What is MongoDB size limit on Openshift?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift

I am developing an application using nodejs and mongodb. I came across Openshift for hosting, they provides 3 free gears each with 512 ram and 1 GB disk space.

MongoDB is in the form of cartridge for Openshift applications, so i am not sure, if i install a MongoDB cartridge for my nodejs application, how much data size will it be allotted for MongoDB .

```
a) Does it limit to 1GB 
b) MongoDB data-size= 1GB - (NodeJS APP space) 
c) or can i have it as a separate gear for MongoDB and access in my application ?
```

Also does Openshift allow to access external cloud datastore like mongoHQ or cloudant

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Great question. In a non-scaled application, DB and lang cartridges share the 1 GB gear storage. Where as in scaled application, DB gets its own gear which means it has 1 GB for itself. For more information on scaling apps, see: https://www.openshift.com/blogs/scaling-in-action-on-openshift

Comment: so in case of free plan, 3 gears are their, so (if required) i can use 1 for db and other 2 for HTTP scaling ?

Comment: Yup. And if you see a need for more resources, you can always sign up for Silver plan which gives you 16 gears with 6GB quota each and upto 1 GB Memory on each. Only caveat with Silver plan is that it is currently available only US and Europe.

Comment: I tried to have a dedicated mongo gear in the free tier, but initializing the mongo server itself exausts the disk space